# UIPicker single component to display multiple arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uipickerview

first comment so I hope Im doing this right.

I'm having a fight with a UIPicker. I am trying to display 2 columns of data in a single picker component. The reason I have chosen to do this within 1 component is that I want the arrays to scroll together, which I can't get multiple components to do.

The trouble is, I can't get this way to work either, as titleForRow and viewForRow will only return one value (as per the rules of C). I tried making them output arrays and dicts but that caused data type errors.
I can get it to work just fine using 1 component, 1 array with viewForRow but that only allows justification the whole field, not parts of the string.

The below code works great and gives a correct answer with return label2; and if changed to return label1 is correct also , How do I get both to display?

```
   - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label1;
    {
        label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 150.0f, 130.0f, 60.0f)];

        label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

        label1.text = [_firstList objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    UILabel *label2;
    {
    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 10.0f, 175.0f, 100.0f)];

      label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        label2.text = [_secondList objectAtIndex:row];
    }
        return label2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your `UIPickerView` to have one component.

Now assuming that your two array `_firstList` and `_secondList` have the same number of objects in them, you have two options:

1. Use the simple `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` method to return a single string build from the two values:

   ```
   - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", _firstList[row], _secondList[row]];
   }
   ```

   Of course you can format the two strings as needed. This is one example.
2. Use `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` like you tried but return a single view that has two labels added to it.

   ```
   - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
       UILabel *label1;
       UILabel *label2;
       if (view) {
           label1 = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
           label1 = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:2];
       } else {
           view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
           UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 130.0f, 40.0f)];
           label1.tag = 1;
           label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
           UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 0.0f, 175.0f, 40.0f)];
           label2.tag = 2;
           label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
           [view addSubview:label1];
           [view addSubview:label2];
       }

       label1.text = _firstList[row];
       label2.text = _secondList[row];

       return view;
   }
   ```

   Note how this properly makes use of the reused view.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this - it's great. Part 1 looks considerably better than anything I got running. Part 2, label1 = [view viewWithTag:1]; throws a  incompatible pointer warning and won't run,(Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UILabel *' from 'UIView *'.). Thanks for your time (and sorry, I'm too new to up vote you).

Comment: I forgot a cast for those lines. I just updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: That's an impressive response time. I'll go answer a few of the things Im good at and get the ability to up vote. Thanks.

Comment: Ive been playing with your 2nd option for a while now and I can't make it work. It's a much superior method as it will allow proper alignment of columns. I can get it to display anything. I can get the method to work with just one array and I can align it nicely, but can't get a second label to work at all. Is this something I'm doing wrong or is example 2 faulty somehow?

Comment: I believe the code in my answer is correct but you need to verify the frames for the labels are correct. It would also be a good idea to set each label's `autoresizingMask` properly to ensure the label's are resized as the parent view is sized.